# child id, unique in the scope of the parentSchema, or in all of the childrens?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

i didn't know how to find my answer in the documentation, that's why i'm bothering you to ask.
i have two schema using mongoose:

```
childSchmea
    name: String


parentSchema
    name: String,
    childrens: [childSchema]
```

and also i have a `Child` and a `Parent` model.
now in rest best practices i saw, if we want *one special* child of *one special* parent, we use this url:

```
/parents/:parentId/children/:childId
```

now each `child` has it's own `id` produced by mongoose.
but is it unique to child's of **another** parent?

for getting the child i should do this:

```
Parent.findById( req.params.moduleId , function(err, mod) {
    if(err) next(err);
    res.json( mod.mod_roles.id( req.params.roleId );
});
```

i mean `childSchema` is **embedded** and it's not a **reference** so:

- i have a child model.
- my child model is not independent, it depends on the parent model. but does it's id is depended too?
  and of course by replacing the `findById` part with this code instead:

my question really is, for getting the child can i use this code instead:

```
Child.findById( req.params.childId , function(err, child) {
     // send the child
});
```

this gives the same result right? or i'm mistaken, and the child's id is unique only in it's parent scope?

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data schema,

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  children: [childSchema]
});

var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);
var Child = mongoose.model('Child', childSchema);
```

If we save the parent as the following codes

```
var parent = new Parent;
var child = new Child({ name: 'Aaron' });

child.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('save child successfully');
});

parent.children.push(child);

parent.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('save parent successfully');

});
```

As result, the documents of collections

```
> db.parents.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e3bf61f3dcb32104b3ea78"), "children" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("56e3bf61f3dcb32104b3ea79"), "name" : "Aaron" } ], "__v" : 0 }
> db.children.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e3bf61f3dcb32104b3ea79"), "name" : "Aaron", "__v" : 0 }
```

We know the same `_id` of children document and saved in the `parents` collection, we can get the child document in this way

```
Child.findById( req.params.childId , function(err, child) {
```

---

However, if we save `parents` and `children` documents in another way,

```
var parent = new Parent({ children: [{ name: 'Matt' }, { name: 'Sarah' }] });
parent.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('save parent successfully');

});
```

The results are

```
> db.parents.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e3c1173832cb24043378d6"), "children" : [ { "name" : "Matt", "_id" : ObjectId("56e3c1173832cb24043378d8") }, { "name" : "Sarah", "_id" : ObjectId("56e3c1173832cb24043378d7") } ], "__v" : 0 }
> db.children.find()
```

There is no children documents saved in the `children` collection, so we **cannot** find child document through

```
Child.findById( req.params.childId , function(err, child) {
```

To access the child document only through

```
Parent.findById( req.params.moduleId , function(err, mod) {
    if(err) next(err);
    res.json( mod.mod_roles.id( req.params.roleId );
});
```